# clip attribute for charGroup is not working D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, position, clip

Currently, I have a simple d3.js chart, but my chart lines do overflow on axis when I am doing zoom.

On the first image, you can see that top is over the Y-axis

[image: first]

When I do zoom, then it goes over axis for all sides

I have tried to add the clip to charContent and do a nesting, but nothing has worked. 
I actually think that trouble is with content and transform the function of D3.js, could you please advice what is wrong?

```js
window.sector = "";

//remove last content from prev. chart before drawing 
  var svg = d3.select("svg");
  svg.selectAll("*").remove();

  d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/9aff70ec-c35c-11e9-9745-9104983546ae", function (error, dataSet) {

    if (error) throw error;
    dataSet = filterData(dataSet)
    type(dataSet);

    //Dimensions
    var margin = { top: 50, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 20 },
      width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    //X and Y lines
    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
      y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    //AXIS GROUP
    x.domain(d3.extent(dataSet, function (d) { return d.trade_date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(dataSet, function (d) { return d.value; })]);


    // Axis X and Y
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
      yAxis = d3.axisRight(y);

    var line = d3.line()
      .x(function (d) { return x(d.trade_date); })
      .y(function (d) { return y(d.value); });

    //AXIS GROUP
    var axisGroup = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var axisX= axisGroup.append("g")
      .attr("class", " axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    var axisY= axisGroup.append("g")
      .attr("class", " axis--y")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
      .call(yAxis);

    //LINE CHART
    var clip = svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("SVG:rect")
      .attr("width", width )
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("x", margin.left)
      .attr("y", margin.top);

    var chartGroup = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "chart-group")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

      var chartContent = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "chart-group");
    
    // Add line 
    chartContent
    .append("path")
      .datum(dataSet)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);

    // Add the scatterplot to line
    chartContent
      .selectAll(".dots")
      .data(dataSet).
      enter().append("circle")
      .attr('class', 'dots')
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.trade_date); })
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .on("mouseover", function (a, b, c) {
        //console.log(a);
        this.attr("classs", 'focus');
      })
      .on("mouseout", function () {
        this.attr("classs", '');
      });
    //LINE CHART

    var zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
      .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
      .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);


    chartGroup.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "zoom")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(zoom);
    
    function zoomed() {
      var t = d3.event.transform;
      chartContent.attr("transform", t)
      d3.selectAll('.line').style("stroke-width", 2/d3.event.transform.k);
     
      axisX.call(xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x)));
      axisY.call(yAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y)));
    }
  });

  function type(d) {
    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
      d[i].trade_date = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d[i].trade_date);
      d[i].value = +d[i].value;
    }
    return d;
  }

  function filterData(data) {
    //console.log(window.sector);
    return data.filter(row => {
      //console.log(window.sector);
      if (sector) return row.sector.toUpperCase() === sector.toUpperCase();
      return true;
    });
  }
```

```css
.chart-group{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.zoom {
cursor: move;
fill: none;
pointer-events: all;
}
.dots{
    stroke:steelblue; 
    fill: slateblue; 
}

.focus{
    fill: black; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
```